# How to get a stack trace from FastMM under C++ Builder?

Tags: c++11, c++builder, fastmm

I managed to install FastMM4 under C++ Builder 2010 but the log file generated is filled with memory dumps or with statements like

> The block is currently used for an object of class: Unknown

Last statement in log is:

```
5 - 12 bytes: TObject x 1       <------- this is mine! I created this leak intentionally!
13 - 20 bytes: Unknown x 8
53 - 68 bytes: std::locale::_Locimp x 1
181 - 212 bytes: Unknown x 1
```

---

I added to my project:

- FastMM4.pas
- FastMM4Messages.pas
- FastMM4Options.inc

The Full Debug Mode (and several other features) were enabled manually in the inc file. The FastMM_FullDebugMode.dll is present in my project's folder.
I use USEOBJ("FastMM4BCB.cpp") in my project file (above 'useform') and I disabled the DynamicRTL (linker) in Project Options.

---

How to get decent info like stack trace?

Comment: Did you install the full version of FastMM?  Did you configure it to enable full debug mode, and to enable logging of call stacks for leaked memory? Did you place the full debug DLL in the same folder as your app?

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Yes. Of course. Without those the manager would not install and I would have not obtained the debug log (txt) on disk  :)